# source a shell script from another script and check return code

Tags: bash, shell

I want to source a file eg name.sh from another script and check the return code and decide on it's error code. If I use

```
source name.sh
```

then if name.sh return non-zero return code my main script stop to run but I need to decide on exit code weather to continue or stop.

If I use

```
ret_code="`source name.sh`"
echo $ret_code
```

then ret_code is null and no error code is printed.
I can't use these:

```
sh name.sh
./name.sh
bash name.sh
```

because name.sh is not executable and I don't want it to be executable

Comment: Why not enclosing the executable code of "name.sh" in a function ?

Comment: @doukremt because my script should run a serial of other scripts in a directory

Comment: The backticks (``) spawn an subordinate shell which then executes `source name.sh`; this is equivalent to `bash name.sh` (assuming $SHELL is bash).

Comment: What do you think is a return code of a sourced file? When you execute `exit` command in the file being sourced then normally the shell will be terminated and no commands after the `source` command will be executed. When you are sourcing a file no new shell is started. --- The variants `sh name.sh` and `bash name.sh` do not require `name.sh` to be executable! You can use them if you do not need to modify your environment in `name.sh` and have it in the parent script.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

File does not need to be executable to run `sh name.sh`. Than use `$?`.

```
sh name.sh
ret_code=$?
```

Comment: I think that you misunderstand Amin's requirement. He is sourcing the file, not running it. The return value of the sourcing is simply the return value of the last command executed.

Answer (score 11):

The return code should be in the variable `$?`.  You can do the following:

```
source name.sh         # Execute shell script
ret_code=$?            # Capture return code
echo $ret_code
```

Comment: if i use source name.sh if name.sh contain exit 1 the code stop to continue

Comment: The purpose of using `source` is to run the script within the current shell.  Hence, the `exit` will stop the current shell as well.  Your original question had an explicit requirement to use `source` and I assumed that you know the consequences.

Comment: I have mentioned that if i use source what problem happen but how ever thank for your help

Comment: The answer does not say what the return code here is. --- In `bash` and in POSIX shells it is the return code of the last command in the sourced file. See: https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_18_14

Answer (score 1):

Amin, the return value of name.sh is simply the return value of the last command executed. Access it using `$?` as usual.

The simplest approach to capturing a return code is to structure "name.sh" so that failed commands result in no more commands being executed (which might succeed and then mask the error). Since you are using bash, you can also use functions. Just move your logic into a function and call it. This way, your `name.sh` becomes a one-liner and the value of `$?` will be whatever the function return.

For example:

```
# cat fred
function f() {complicated; logic; here; export FRED="asdf";return 1;}
f
# source fred
# echo $?
1
# echo $FRED
asdf
```

However, if you put your logic into a function, then you might as well source the file and then call the function at your leisure.

```
# cat fred
function f() {complicated; logic; here; export FRED="asdf";return 1;}
# source fred
# f && echo "that worked!" || echo "failed again"
failed again
# echo $FRED
asdf
```